# Can I enumerate properties that only exist as getter/setter functions?

Tags: javascript

Given a class like this

```
class Stuff {
  set b(v) {
  }
  get c() {
    return 'x'
  }
}

const x = new Stuff
console.log(x.hasOwnProperty('b'))
```

how can I test for "properties" b and c, or list all such getter/setters? `hasOwnProperty` does not show them to exist.

Comment: compare `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(x)` to `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like all properties defined with method syntax (whether getter/setter or not), they're on the prototype, not the instance, so call `hasOwnProperty` on the prototype:

```js
class Stuff {
  set b(v) {
  }
  get c() {
    return 'x'
  }
  notGetter() {}
}

const x = new Stuff
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(x).hasOwnProperty('b'),
  Stuff.prototype.hasOwnProperty('b')
);

const allGettersSetters = Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Stuff.prototype))
  .filter(([, value]) => !value.hasOwnProperty('value'))
  .map(([key]) => key);
console.log(allGettersSetters);
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Do you perhaps also know why 1default` does not show up on the prototype here?

```
lass Stuff {
  default = 3
  set b(v) {
  }
  get c() {
    return 'x'
  }
  notGetter() {}
}

const x = new Stuff
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(x).hasOwnProperty('b'),
  Stuff.prototype.hasOwnProperty('b'),
  Stuff.prototype.hasOwnProperty('default'),
  x.hasOwnProperty('default'),
);
```

Comment: It's not on the prototype, it's on the instance. Class fields - that is, `=`s directly inside the class body - are syntax sugar for, in the constructor, `this.someProp = someVal`. So it doesn't show up when examining the prototype.